# Programatic access of a hash element

Tags: perl, hash

Can anyone make this print "4" by replacing the PFM block??

```
my %hash;
$hash{1}{2}{3}=4;

my @key=qw(1 2 3);

my $key;

for(@key){PFM}

print $hash{$key}
```

Comment: No. Because $key has the value of undef by the time you get to the print statement.

Comment: No. Because you're not trying to fetch a value from %hash. (What @tadmc said makes no sense. PFM could set `$key` to something other than undef.)

Comment: How do you delete a comment on SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my %hash;
$hash{1}{2}{3}=4;

my @key=qw(1 2 3);

my $data = \%hash;
for(@key){
  $data = $data->{$_}
}

print $data
```

Comment: That's what I was missing!  my $data = \%hash; was the key to whole thing.  Excellent work!

Answer (score 5):

```
my $val = \%hash;
$val //= $val->{$_} for @key;
say $val;
```

or you could use [Data::Diver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Diver)

```
use Data::Diver qw( Dive );
say Dive(\%hash, @key);
```

Neither version will vivify anything if any part of the key doesn't exist.

---

If you want to set a value using such a key:

```
my $p = \\%hash;
$p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @key;
$$p = 5;
```

or

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveRef );
my $ref = DiveRef(\%hash, map \$_, @key);
$$ref = 5;
```

or

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );
DiveVal(\%hash, map \$_, @key) = 5;
```

(The `map \$_,` is required to make Data::Diver make hashes instead of arrays for numerical keys.)

Comment: This is very interesting and useful.  I voted this up too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But it's probably not what you wanted:

```
$key = "X";
$hash{X} = 4;
```

4 is not a value of the %hash originally:

```
my @fours = grep $_ == 4, values %hash;
print "[@fours]\n"; # prints '[]'
```