# Adressing a hash of hashes with an array

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

This is my problem:

I have a file-system like data-structure:

```
%fs = (
    "home" => {
        "test.file"  => { 
            type => "file",
            owner => 1000, 
            content => "Hello World!",
        },
    },
    "etc"  => { 
        "passwd"  => { 
            type => "file",
            owner => 0, 
            content => "testuser:testusershash",
            },
        "conf"  => { 
            "test.file"  => { 
                type => "file",
                owner => 1000, 
                content => "Hello World!",
            },
        },
    },
);
```

Now, to get the content of `/etc/conf/test.file` I need `$fs{"etc"}{"conf"}{"test.file"}{"content"}`, but my input is an array and looks like this: `("etc","conf","test.file")`.

So, because the length of the input is varied, I don't know how to access the values of the hash. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671233/programatic-access-of-a-hash-element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789420/how-would-you-create-and-traverse-a-hash-of-hashes-of-depth-n-whereby-the-val http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965006/convert-string-a-b-c-to-hash-a-b-c-in-perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @a = ("etc","conf","test.file");

my $h = \%fs;
while (my $v = shift @a) {
  $h = $h->{$v};
}
print $h->{type};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a loop. In each step, you proceed one level deeper into the structure.

```
my @path = qw/etc conf test.file/;
my %result = %fs;
while (@path) {
    %result = %{ $result{shift @path} };
}
print $result{content};
```

You can also use [Data::Diver](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDiver).

Answer (score 1):

Same logic as what others given, but uses `foreach`

```
@keys = qw(etc conf test.file content);
$r = \%fs ;
$r = $r->{$_} foreach (@keys);
print $r;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pname = '/etc/conf/test.file';
@names = split '/', $pname;
$fh = \%fs;
for (@names) {
    $fh = $fh->{"$_"} if $_;
}
print $fh->{'content'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Path::Class accepts an array.  It also gives you an object with helper methods and handles cross platform slash issues.

https://metacpan.org/module/Path::Class

Answer (score -1):

You can just build the hash element expression and call `eval`. This is tidier if it is wrapped in a subroutine

```
my @path = qw/ etc conf test.file /;

print hash_at(\%fs, \@path)->{content}, "\n";

sub hash_at {
  my ($hash, $path) = @_;
  $path = sprintf q($hash->{'%s'}), join q('}{'), @$path;
  return eval $path;
}
```

Comment: Can the down voters please explain? There is no problem with `eval` as long as the source of the string is reliable. Here we have built it ourselves so it is trustworthy.